# How to be statistically rigorous when working with observational data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, sample, observational-study

I'm working with a sample of ~100k data points from a population of ~800k. I'm analyzing the sample to detect patterns that would help me answer a research question of the form: Is X happening in the sample, if so how many? I am looking for help in how to be statistically rigorous in the measurements I make?

For example, after some analysis I arrived at a number 257.

1. Could I (or should I) express standard error of the sample based on `p = 257/100,000` using population proportion calculations?
2. If I go through with (1), could I express a confidence interval for the number 257?
3. Could I (or should I) draw another sample from the population and do some hypothesis tests?

I understand I can express a quantity along with a confidence interval for an observational sample, but I'm intrigued to learn what that represents for the population?

Please feel free to add reading material for reference in your answers! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Confidence intervals are a great accompaniment to any estimate. The main worry about observational data is confounding.  From what you've told us, it doesn't sound like confounding should be an issue (unless there was some bias in your sampling), but that really depends on the details.  Can you share more re: the purpose of the study?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The ~800k data points are a population pre-filtered on parameters like country. I'm limited in what I can share, but broadly speaking I'm looking at an application's usage data and I want to measure the prevalence of a specific type of behavior. I hope this helps!